# Reading ajax data in nodejs

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am doing ajax call from client side. Want to  Pass data (value of city) to client side. When i tried to access value at server side i am not able to access its value. Here's the code

Server:

```
var express = require("express"),
http = require("http"),
bodyParser= require("body-parser"),
yelp = require("yelp"),
app;

// Create our Express-powered HTTP server
/ and have it listen on port 3000
app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);


// set up a static file directory to use for default routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// set up our routes
// for user login
app.get("/yelp", function (req, res) {

var city = req.query.city;
var yelp = require("yelp").createClient({
consumer_key: "xyz", 
consumer_secret: "xyz",
token: "xyz",
token_secret: "xyz"
});

console.log("city="+city);
// See http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
yelp.search({term: "restaurants", location:"fullerton" , limit: 5 },    function  (error, data) {
console.log(error);
res.format({
    'application/jsonp': function(){
res.send('yelp('+JSON.stringify(data)+');');
}
});
});

});
```

Client side ajax call function:

```
var main = function () {
"use strict";
var $button= $("#search");   
$button.on("click",function(){
var input_city= $("#city").val();
$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "/yelp",
        data: JSON.stringify({city :input_city }),
        jsonpCallback: "yelp",
        contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp"
       /* success: function(msg){
            console.log("success called");
            var $result = $.parseJSON(msg);
            console.log($result.businesses[0].name);
            $('#list').append("<div>"+$result.businesses[0].name+"    </div>");
        },
        error: function (errormessage){
            console.log("error called");
            $('#list').append(errormessage);
    }*/
    })
    .done(function (data,status){

  $('#list').html("");
    var i = 0;
   for(i=0; i < data.businesses.length; i++)
   {
    $('#list').append("<div class='business'>");
    $('#list').append("<div class='business_name'>");
     $('#list').append(data.businesses[i].name);
    $('#list').append("</div>");
     $('#list').append("<div class='business_address'>");
     $('#list').append(data.businesses[i].location.display_address);
     $('#list').append("</div>");
    $('#list').append("<div class='business_phone'>");
     $('#list').append(data.businesses[i].phone);
    $('#list').append("</div>");
    $('#list').append("<div class='business_rating'>");
     $('#list').append(data.businesses[i].rating);
    $('#list').append("</div>");
    $('#list').append("</div>");
   }
    })
    .fail(function (data, status){
    console.log("fail called");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
});


            });
};
```

Output at server side console
    city = undefined

Comment: The contentType you are setting for your request + the format of the data you are sending doesn't match what your server expects. The default contentType should be fine, and you don't need to stringify your data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your server is actually expecting `city` to be a query string. On your client side, do:

```
    url: "/yelp?city=" + input_city,
```

and remove the `data:...` line.

Comment: Or, he could keep `data:` and not stringify it, which would allow jQuery to encode the data automatically.